# Calculate $\int_{c(0,1)}^{}\sin(\frac{1}{z})dz$ with the help of the Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

we have  $\int_{c(0,1)}^{}\sin(\frac{1}{z})dz=\int_{c(0,1)}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(\frac{1}{z})^{2n+1}dz=$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty }\int_{c(0,1)}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(\frac{1}{z})^{2n+1}dz= \color{blue}{\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}}_{=\sin(1)}} 2\pi i$$

(the integral is a standar integral equal to $2\pi i$)

**so the answer is $\sin(1)2\pi i$** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The answer is $2\pi i$, since$$\int_{c(0,1)}z^{n}\,\mathrm dz=\begin{cases}2\pi i&\text{ if }n=-1\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Anyway, it seemes to be that it's more natural to say that$$\int_{c(0,1)}\sin\left(\frac1z\right)\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\sin\left(\frac1z\right)\right)=2\pi i,$$since$$\sin\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac{\color{red}1}z-\frac1{3!z^3}+\frac1{5!z^5}+\cdots$$

Comment: i dont know yet the res theorem , where is my mistake because it looks correct to me, does that mean $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}=1$ ?

Comment: No. Your error lies in assuming that each integral $\int_{c(0,1)}\left(\frac1z\right)^{2n+1}$ is equal to $1$. It0s equal to $2\pi i$ if $n=0$ and to $0$ otherwise.